# C++11, Is it possible to force an instance to be extern but also a constant expression of a non-type template parameter?

Tags: c++11, templates, constexpr, type-traits, linkage

Using C++11, g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18).

Lets pretend I have a templated function (pardon my terminology if it isn't quite right).

I want to perform a "general" algorithm based on what was supposed to be compile-time instances of "field".  Where the only things that really changed are these constants which I moved into trait classes (only added one here but imagine there are more).  Originally I was declaring it as

```
constexpr field FIELD1{1};
```

However in C++11, non-type template params need to have external linkage (unlike C++14 which can have internal and external linkage?).  So because not's in the same translation unit I needed to use extern in order to give it external linkage (sorry if I butchered that explanation also).  But by defining it extern I can't define it using constexpr and it seems that losing that constexpr constructor this field is no longer a valid constant expression to qualify as a non-type template param.

Any suggestions if there is some way I can get around this? Open to a new method of doing things. Below is a simplified (incomplete, and non-compiling version to get the gist of the organization).

So the error I am seeing is along the lines of

error: the value of ‘FIELD1’ is not usable in a constant expression

note: ‘FIELD1’ was not declared ‘constexpr’
 extern const field FIELD1;
Not quite sure what could be a best alternative.

I can get rid of the second error by removing the constexpr from the constructor. But then I don't know how to approach the constant expression issue.

*field.H*

```
struct field
{
    int thingone;

    constexpr field(int i):thingone(i){}
};

extern const field FIELD1;
```

*field.C*

```
#include "field.H"
const field FIELD1{0};
```

*field_traits.H*

```
#include "field.H"

template< const field& T >
class fieldTraits;

template< >
class fieldTraits<FIELD1>
{
    public:
        // Let's say I have common field names
        // with different constants that I want to plug
        // into the "function_name" algorithm
        static constexpr size_t field_val = 1; 
};
```

*function.H*

```
#include "field.H"

template< const field& T, typename TT = fieldTraits<T> >
void function_name()
{
    // Let's pretend I'm doing something useful with that data
    std::cout << T.thingone << std::endl;
    std::cout << TT::field_val << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: "But by defining it extern I can't define it using constexpr" -- I was about to ask "why not?". To be clear, you can if you continue to provide an initialiser, but you'll get an error for multiple definitions if the header is included in multiple translation units, so that won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So because not's in the same translation unit I needed to use extern in order to give it external linkage (sorry if I butchered that explanation also). But by defining it extern I can't define it using constexpr [...]

Per my comment, you can. It wouldn't work for you, but it's a step that helps in coming up with something that would work:

```
extern constexpr int i = 10;
```

This is perfectly valid, gives `i` external linkage, and makes `i` usable in constant expressions.

But it doesn't allow multiple definitions, so it can't work in a header file which is included in multiple translation units.

Ordinarily, the way around that is with `inline`:

```
extern inline constexpr int i = 10;
```

But variables cannot be declared `inline` in C++11.

Except... when they don't need to be declared `inline` because the effect has already been achieved implicitly:

```
struct S {
  static constexpr int i = 10;
};
```

Now, `S::i` has external linkage *and* is usable in constant expressions!

You may not even need to define your own class for this, depending on the constant's type: consider `std::integral_constant`. You can write

```
using i = std::integral_constant<int, 10>;
```

and now `i::value` will do exactly what you want.

Comment: That's looks like a pretty useful feature. It seems to work well w/a single integral constant but not a constexpr data structure that has say..more than one member variable. Thoughts?

Comment: It seems that for my case I might have to make a class that holds this "field" data structure.  struct S { static constexpr field FIELD1{1} }; might work to give FIELD1 external linkage.

Comment: @user1945925 If you want to have multiple data members in a single container type, then yes, you'd need to create your own type, I think.

Comment: add  that to your response and I can select it

Comment: @user1945925 Okay, I've changed `static const int i = 10;` to `static constexpr int i = 10;`; there was no real benefit in the `const` version anyway. I've also edited my mention of `std::integral_constant` to no longer suggest it for all types.